# services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration> purpose in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

We need to read from multiple appsettings based on local or not. We achieved this by adding `appsettings.local.json`.

But we see that although we add this file and set up necessary configurations, we were not able to read config data from `appsettings.local.json`, all time it saw  `appsettings.json`.

Let me tell by code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    CreateWebHostBuilder(args, config).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args, IConfiguration config)
{
    var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config))
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    return webHostBuilder;
}
```

In `CreateWebHostBuilder`, if we do not add `.ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config))` we could not read data from `appsettings.local.json`. After adding this, we can read from `appsettings.local.json`. So my question is what happened in here? Can someone provide a reasonable explanation?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing there is that you create a separate configuration builder that loads its own sources. You do this although the default web host builder already contains a few configuration sources, including the `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.<environment>.json` files.

By saying `services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config)` you are effectively replacing the default configuration with your own configuration. While this will probably have the right effect most of the time, I can imagine that it can lead to some problems later since you effectively have two different configurations within your application (although one of them—the default one—is mostly inaccessible).

I would generally recommend you not to do this but instead to change the default configuration so that it loads all your desired sources. You can do that by calling [`WebHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderextensions.configureappconfiguration?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args, IConfiguration config)
{
    var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", optional: true);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    return webHostBuilder;
}
```

This will now add another JSON file to the default configuration builder. So the default `IConfiguration` will take the configuration values from that source as well. This way, you won’t be needing to create the `ConfigurationBuilder` within your `Program.cs`.

Note that the `appsettings.local.json` is now the last configuration source, so whatever settings are configured there will overwrite previously configured settings. So be aware of this if you are using command line arguments or environment variables.

Finally note that if you meant to use the `local` file only on a specific local environment, then you can also just [set the hosting environment to be `local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-the-environment) to load the `appsettings.local.json` automatically as part of the default configuration setup. This is because the default host builder will automatically pick up `appsettings.<environment>.json` if it exists.

Comment: Thanks for answer. As I have understood you advice not to  replacing the default configuration with my own configuration. Instead change(by using ConfigureAppConfiguration) the default configuration. you say.   But you said `(although one of them—the default one—is mostly inaccessible)`   I could not understand this. We can use 2 of them and if there is no config Key in local appsetting , it can read from original app setting

Comment: You have to differentiate between a configuration (i.e. `IConfiguration`) and configuration sources here: The default configuration uses a few default configuration sources (`appsettings.json`, `appsettings.<environment>.json`, environment variables etc.). In *your* custom configuration, you are also using a few configuration sources (`appsettings.json`, `appsettings.local.json`, environment variables, command line arguments). Both configurations make use of `appsettings.json` as a source, so if a later source does not overwrite a value, the value from the `appsettings.json` will be used.

Comment: By doing `AddSingleton(config)`, you are now replacing the default configuration (which its sources) with your custom configuration (using those new sources). So access to the old configuration object is mostly prevented. That means that your new sources will be used when accessing the configuration.

Comment: Yo said  In custom configuration "so if a later source does not overwrite a value, the value from the appsettings.json will be used"  but is it not also available for default configuration? I think same behaviour will occur with default configuration. Am I missing stg?

Comment: Yes, the behavior with multiple sources is the same: Later sources can overwrite earlier sources. So the default configuration works the same way. It’s just by replacing the default configuration with your custom configuration, you are effectively disabling the default configuration altogether. So at that point, only your custom configuration matters.

Comment: so you do not advice this , more effectively I should add  `.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", optional: true);
        })`    you have mentioned about

Comment: Yes, exactly. Don’t replace the default configuration but just adjust it so it fits your needs.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that since things that traditionally override the JSON config (environment variables, etc.) will have already been included, your local JSON will now override *everything*. If you still want environment variables to override, for example, you'll need to add that config provider again.